# Convenient way to make an UIImageView ExpressibleByStringLiteral

Tags: swift, ios, extension-methods, constructor, casting

I want to reduce boiler-plate code and write like this when developing in iOS:

```
let imgView: UIImageView = "share_fareware_text_bg"
```

Here is implementation code:

```
class ImageView: UIImageView, ExpressibleByStringLiteral{
    public convenience required init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(image: UIImage(named: value))
    }
}
```

Then I can call:

```
let imgView: ImageView = "share_fareware_text_bg"
```

Is there any better way to do it more naturally?

Comment: Do you create all image views programmatically, and not in the Storyboard?

Comment: Storyboard is nice. Our team mainly build UI programmatically. This is the main code style in Shanghai

Comment: A convenience initializer from String would be more appropriate/make more sense to me. Plus, using string literals all over your code is prone to error, and isn't ideal for teamwork, better use a resources Struct. Have a look here https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift

Comment: `R` is wonderful

Answer (score 2):

If you do want that feel, the way you do that is this:

```
let yourImageView = "share_icon.png".imageView
```

Write an extension *on string*.

Similarly, you often see extensions on integers.

(As has been mentioned, note that of course you never use string literals for things like file names, in code.)